# How do I use last.fm in Rhythmbox without subscribing?

Tags: rhythmbox

If I subscribe to last.fm will I be able to listen to last.fm through Rhythmbox using the plugin available in the repositories, or is there an alternative way to do this without subscribing?  I would like to be able to listen from within rhythmbox.  Can anyone confirm that the plugin does play last.fm created radio stations if you subscribe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works out of the box- just hit last.fm in the side bar, login & authorise RhythmBox and you can listen to last.fm stations. No need to install anything extra from the repo's.

---

For some people the lastfm plugin works if you first disable the plugin and re-enable the plugin again.

Comment: It's not working for me is the issue.  I can login and authorise no problem.  I'm getting information from Last.fm (recently listed tracks, etc.) but if I try to create a radio station or click on a track or artist and click listen to similar artist nothing happens.  The right pane listing tracks and what not is comletely blank.

Comment: I can listen using the scrobbler, but this is not ideal, as I would like to keep my musical habits consolidated in rhythmbox.

Comment: Does the last.fm application from the repositories work? If not its probably a network issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.  When I said the scrobbler I was speaking about the last.fm app from the repositories.  So you can confirm that this does work without subscription in rhythmbox in 12.04?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. No you still need to subscribe to last.fm, but its free.

Comment: Maybe there is confusion in terms.  I have an account, but subscription says it is $3.00 per month.  I had read a post about a user asking why he could no longer listen to last.fm in rhythmbox and he was told because that is now only offered to subscribers, others would have to use the last.fm scrobbler or the web site.  But you are saying you can listen to last.fm without paying subscription service, only having an account?

Comment: It works for me fine and I haven't paid last.fm for a subscription. So yes, it works with a free account in my case at least.

Comment: I disabled, and re-enabled the plugin and viola it's working.  Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

(I authorized last.fm in `rhythmbox` like Gary mentioned, but I can't listen to any stations. However all the information like the track history etc shows up. I also disabled and re-enabled but still I can't create or listen to the radio station.)

A solution for my problem:

I updated `rhythmbox` by following [the instructions here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/rhythmbox-297-released-with-improved.html) and entering these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/rhythmbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I then updated the plugins by referring to [this discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-base0.10/+question/198458) and entered the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

And now I can play my music and last.fm. However I still can't access the radio stations I already had in my last.fm profile so I had to create a new one, which I don't mind at all, but some might find it annoying.

UPDATE: Starting from last week, it has stopped working and I haven't found solution yet. The checking on and off in the edit plugins doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

At least as of now (Dec 2013) streaming is only available to paid Last.fm subscribers.

To double check that this is the issue run `rhythmbox -ddd` in a terminal and watch
for

```
The Webservices API key supplied does not have permission to
stream / create new radio trials
```